# How to deal with overlapping IP ranges in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have downloaded the raw text file of IPFire location database from [here](https://git.ipfire.org/?p=location/location-database.git;a=tree), I tried to convert the data to a sqlite3 database and I succeeded in doing so.

However there are lots of overlapping IP ranges, and I want to merge the IP overlapping ranges that share the same country and ASN, and split the overlapping IP ranges into discrete IP ranges if they don't.

For example, if I am not mistaken, 1.0.0.0/8 denotes a network, the starting address is 1.0.0.0 and the end is 1.255.255.255, and there are 16777216 addresses in the network. However immediately after the first example, which is the first entry in the data, the second entry is 1.0.0.0/24, which is completely contained in the first range.

But they don't share same ASN and country. I think all IP addresses in the larger range is assigned to the first party unless they are assigned to the second party, in which case the second party overrides the first in the ranges assigned to the second party.

There are lots of cases like this.

Given the example input:

```py
data = [
    (16777216, 33554431, '1.0.0.0', '1.255.255.255', 16777216, '1.0.0.0/8', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, '1.0.0.0/24', 'AS13335', 'Australia'),
    (16777472, 16777727, '1.0.1.0', '1.0.1.255', 256, '1.0.1.0/24', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16777728, 16778239, '1.0.2.0', '1.0.3.255', 512, '1.0.2.0/23', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16778240, 16779263, '1.0.4.0', '1.0.7.255', 1024, '1.0.4.0/22', 'AS38803', 'Australia'),
    (16778496, 16778751, '1.0.5.0', '1.0.5.255', 256, '1.0.5.0/24', 'AS38803', 'Australia'),
    (16779264, 16781311, '1.0.8.0', '1.0.15.255', 2048, '1.0.8.0/21', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16781312, 16785407, '1.0.16.0', '1.0.31.255', 4096, '1.0.16.0/20', 'Unknown', 'Japan'),
    (16781312, 16781567, '1.0.16.0', '1.0.16.255', 256, '1.0.16.0/24', 'AS2519', 'Japan'),
    (16785408, 16793599, '1.0.32.0', '1.0.63.255', 8192, '1.0.32.0/19', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16785408, 16785663, '1.0.32.0', '1.0.32.255', 256, '1.0.32.0/24', 'AS141748', 'China'),
    (16793600, 16809983, '1.0.64.0', '1.0.127.255', 16384, '1.0.64.0/18', 'AS18144', 'Japan'),
    (16809984, 16842751, '1.0.128.0', '1.0.255.255', 32768, '1.0.128.0/17', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16809984, 16826367, '1.0.128.0', '1.0.191.255', 16384, '1.0.128.0/18', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16809984, 16818175, '1.0.128.0', '1.0.159.255', 8192, '1.0.128.0/19', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16809984, 16810239, '1.0.128.0', '1.0.128.255', 256, '1.0.128.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16810240, 16810495, '1.0.129.0', '1.0.129.255', 256, '1.0.129.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16810496, 16811007, '1.0.130.0', '1.0.131.255', 512, '1.0.130.0/23', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16811008, 16811263, '1.0.132.0', '1.0.132.255', 256, '1.0.132.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16811264, 16811519, '1.0.133.0', '1.0.133.255', 256, '1.0.133.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16812032, 16812287, '1.0.136.0', '1.0.136.255', 256, '1.0.136.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16812288, 16812543, '1.0.137.0', '1.0.137.255', 256, '1.0.137.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16812544, 16812799, '1.0.138.0', '1.0.138.255', 256, '1.0.138.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16812800, 16813055, '1.0.139.0', '1.0.139.255', 256, '1.0.139.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16813312, 16813567, '1.0.141.0', '1.0.141.255', 256, '1.0.141.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16814080, 16818175, '1.0.144.0', '1.0.159.255', 4096, '1.0.144.0/20', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16818176, 16826367, '1.0.160.0', '1.0.191.255', 8192, '1.0.160.0/19', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16818176, 16819199, '1.0.160.0', '1.0.163.255', 1024, '1.0.160.0/22', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16819200, 16819455, '1.0.164.0', '1.0.164.255', 256, '1.0.164.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16819456, 16819711, '1.0.165.0', '1.0.165.255', 256, '1.0.165.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16819712, 16819967, '1.0.166.0', '1.0.166.255', 256, '1.0.166.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16819968, 16820223, '1.0.167.0', '1.0.167.255', 256, '1.0.167.0/24', 'AS23969', 'Thailand')
]
```

How to get the desired output:

```py
[
    (16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, '1.0.0.0/24', 'AS13335', 'Australia'),
    (16777472, 16777727, '1.0.1.0', '1.0.1.255', 256, '1.0.1.0/24', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16777728, 16778239, '1.0.2.0', '1.0.3.255', 512, '1.0.2.0/23', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16778240, 16779263, '1.0.4.0', '1.0.7.255', 1024, '1.0.4.0/22', 'AS38803', 'Australia'),
    (16779264, 16781311, '1.0.8.0', '1.0.15.255', 2048, '1.0.8.0/21', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16781312, 16781567, '1.0.16.0', '1.0.16.255', 256, '1.0.16.0/24', 'AS2519', 'Japan'),
    (16781568, 16783615, '1.0.17.0', '1.0.24.255', 2048, '1.0.17.0/21', 'Unknown', 'Japan'),
    (16783616, 16784639, '1.0.25.0', '1.0.28.255', 1024, '1.0.25.0/22', 'Unknown', 'Japan'),
    (16784640, 16785151, '1.0.29.0', '1.0.30.255', 512, '1.0.29.0/23', 'Unknown', 'Japan'),
    (16785152, 16785407, '1.0.31.0', '1.0.31.255', 256, '1.0.31.0/24', 'Unknown', 'Japan'),
    (16785408, 16785663, '1.0.32.0', '1.0.32.255', 256, '1.0.32.0/24', 'AS141748', 'China'),
    (16785664, 16789759, '1.0.33.0', '1.0.48.255', 4096, '1.0.33.0/20', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16789760, 16791807, '1.0.49.0', '1.0.56.255', 2048, '1.0.49.0/21', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16791808, 16792831, '1.0.57.0', '1.0.60.255', 1024, '1.0.57.0/22', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16792832, 16793343, '1.0.61.0', '1.0.62.255', 512, '1.0.61.0/23', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16793344, 16793599, '1.0.63.0', '1.0.63.255', 256, '1.0.63.0/24', 'Unknown', 'China'),
    (16793600, 16809983, '1.0.64.0', '1.0.127.255', 16384, '1.0.64.0/18', 'AS18144', 'Japan'),
    (16809984, 16842751, '1.0.128.0', '1.0.255.255', 32768, '1.0.128.0/17', 'AS23969', 'Thailand'),
    (16842752, 25231359, '1.1.0.0', '1.128.255.255', 8388608, '1.1.0.0/9', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (25231360, 29425663, '1.129.0.0', '1.192.255.255', 4194304, '1.129.0.0/10', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (29425664, 31522815, '1.193.0.0', '1.224.255.255', 2097152, '1.193.0.0/11', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (31522816, 32571391, '1.225.0.0', '1.240.255.255', 1048576, '1.225.0.0/12', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (32571392, 33095679, '1.241.0.0', '1.248.255.255', 524288, '1.241.0.0/13', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (33095680, 33357823, '1.249.0.0', '1.252.255.255', 262144, '1.249.0.0/14', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (33357824, 33488895, '1.253.0.0', '1.254.255.255', 131072, '1.253.0.0/15', 'Unknown', 'Australia'),
    (33488896, 33554431, '1.255.0.0', '1.255.255.255', 65536, '1.255.0.0/16', 'Unknown', 'Australia')
]
```

I used the following functions to assist me in creating the output, but I generated the output by hand:

```py
import re

MAX_IPV4 = 2**32-1
le255 = r'(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)'
IPV4_PATTERN = re.compile(rf'^({le255}\.){{3}}{le255}$')

def parse_ipv4(ip: str) -> int:
    assert IPV4_PATTERN.match(ip)
    a, b, c, d = ip.split('.')
    return (int(a) << 24) + (int(b) << 16) + (int(c) << 8) + int(d)

def to_ipv4(number: int) -> str:
    assert 0 <= number <= MAX_IPV4
    return ".".join(str(number >> i & 255) for i in range(24, -1, -8))

def parse_network(network):
    start_ip, slash = network.split('/')
    start = parse_ipv4(start_ip)
    slash = int(slash)
    count = 2 ** (32 - slash)
    end = start + count - 1
    return start, end, start_ip, to_ipv4(end), count, network

def split_network(start, end, asn='Unknown', country='Unknown'):
    count = end - start + 1
    start = to_ipv4(start)
    binary = f'{count:032b}'
    i = binary.index('1') + 1
    ones = binary.count('1')
    subnets = []
    for n in range(ones):
        item = parse_network(f'{start}/{i+n}')
        subnets.append((*item, asn, country))
        start = to_ipv4(item[1]+1)
    return subnets
```

I tried the following code and it isn't working:

```
indices = [(e[0], e[1], i) for i, e in enumerate(data)]
for k, e in enumerate(data):
    start, end = e[:2]
    for i_start, i_end, i in indices.copy():
        if i_start <= start < i_end and (start, end) != (i_start, i_end):
            if e[-2:] == data[i][-2:]:
                print(True)
                if (start, end, k) in indices:
                    indices.remove((start, end, k))
            else:
                indices.remove((i_start, i_end, i))
                indices.append((end+1, i_end, i))
                if start > i_start:
                    indices.append((i_start, start-1, i))
```

What is a smart way to split overlapping IP ranges that are different and merge them if they are the same? I want a smart algorithm, better than brute-force, because I literally have millions of entries to process.

---

Update:

I tried to nest the overlapping ranges, and my code gives wrong output, and I don't know how to fix it:

```
indices = [
    (16777216, 33554431, 0),
    (16777216, 16777471, 1),
    (16777472, 16777727, 2),
    (16777728, 16778239, 3),
    (16778240, 16779263, 4),
    (16778496, 16778751, 5),
    (16779264, 16781311, 6),
    (16781312, 16785407, 7),
    (16781312, 16781567, 8),
    (16785408, 16793599, 9),
    (16785408, 16785663, 10),
    (16793600, 16809983, 11),
    (16809984, 16842751, 12),
    (16809984, 16826367, 13),
    (16809984, 16818175, 14),
    (16809984, 16810239, 15),
    (16810240, 16810495, 16),
    (16810496, 16811007, 17),
    (16811008, 16811263, 18),
    (16811264, 16811519, 19),
    (16812032, 16812287, 20),
    (16812288, 16812543, 21),
    (16812544, 16812799, 22),
    (16812800, 16813055, 23),
    (16813312, 16813567, 24),
    (16814080, 16818175, 25),
    (16818176, 16826367, 26),
    (16818176, 16819199, 27),
    (16819200, 16819455, 28),
    (16819456, 16819711, 29),
    (16819712, 16819967, 30),
    (16819968, 16820223, 31)
]
def nest_overlaps(indices):
    if not indices:
        return
    first = indices[:][0]
    if len(indices) == 1:
        return [first]
    tree = {first: {}}
    top_start, top_end = first[:2]
    for i, (start, end, j) in enumerate(indices[1:]):
        if start > top_end:
            break
        if top_start <= start < top_end and (start, end) != (top_start, top_end):
            tree[first][(start, end, j)] = nest_overlaps(indices[i+1:])
    return tree
```

Comment: Could you please give a smaller example of desired input and output, that makes it clear how to calculate the desired result by hand?

Comment: You need to use an efficient data structure for this, like a radix trie. There's a Python library called py-radix that fits the bill. You'll want to go through your list and build up a tree, storing the data you need in each node's `data` attribute. Then you can go through the tree by longest prefix (most specific network) and pull out the ones you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the entries by starting IP increasing, then length decreasing.

As you process, you have a list of currently open ranges.  This should be kept organized by decreasing ending IP, and then break ties on length. It will usually be fairly short and is mostly a stack so I will call it `stack`.  At all points the top of the current stack is the currently open one.

What you do is process the entries in order, knowing the last IP that you processed.  Whenever you see a new entry, you process the stack up until that IP (emitting ranges, popping entries, and so on), and then add the current IP range to the appropriate place in the stack (usually on top).